# java ODE with complex numbers

Tags: java, apache, math, complex-numbers, ode

I am currently trying to compute an ODE in java using the apache commons math library (see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/ode.html) so that i can run the function on hadoop. The problem is that as part of my ODE's it uses complex numbers and there does not appear to be any way of handling complex numbers within this framework (both the inputs and outputs of org.apache.commons.math3.ode.FirstOrderDifferentialEquations are simple double values).

The question is, are there any other libraries that performs such a task with complex numbers or is there a method i can use to translate real integration to complex ones?

The following is the last 3 ODE's in matlab code where u2 is complex.

```
function dy = pricing_odes(tau, y , u1 , u2 , sigma_c , kappa_g , theta , kappa_psi , sigma_cpsi , sigma_cg , phi)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

alpha = y(1,:);
beta3 = y(2,:);
beta4 = y(3,:);
beta5 = y(4,:);
beta6 = y(5,:);
beta7 = y(6,:);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% d beta5 / d tau
dy(4,:) = 2 * sigma_cpsi^2 * beta5^2 + (-2*kappa_psi - 2*sigma_cpsi * u2) * beta5 ...
+ 2 * sigma_cg * sigma_cpsi * beta5 * beta7 + 0.5 * sigma_cg * beta7^2 - sigma_cg * u2 * beta7 + ...
0.5*u2*(u2-1);

% d beta6 /d tau
dy(5,:) = 2 * sigma_cg^2 * beta6^2 - 2 * kappa_g * beta6 + kappa_psi * phi * beta7 + 2 * sigma_cg * sigma_cpsi * beta6 * beta7 ...
+ 0.5 * sigma_cpsi^2 * beta7^2;

% d beta7 /d tau
dy(6,:) = sigma_cg * sigma_cpsi * beta7^2 + (-kappa_g - kappa_psi - sigma_cpsi * u2) * beta7 + ...
2 * kappa_psi * phi * beta5 + 4 * sigma_cg * sigma_cpsi * beta5 * beta6 + 2 * sigma_cpsi^2 * beta5 * beta7 + ...
2 * sigma_cg^2 * beta6 * beta7 - 2 * sigma_cg * u2 * beta6;
```

Comment: Are these the kinds of ODEs where you could solve separately for the real part and the imaginary part?  Or are the two not independent?  Perhaps you could include an example of a typical ODE that you'd have to solve.

Comment: Unfortunately these are riccati equations, which, if i understand correctly, due to their non linearity, means that the real and imaginary parts are dependent on each other.

Comment: I've added the last 3 ODE's as they appear in matlab. variable u2 is complex

Answer (score 0):

It turns that this is simply an issue of representation and the actual integration routines do not need to care whether the numbers are simple or complex. To solve the above with the apache framework, i had to double the dimensionality of my FirstOrderDifferentialEquations object whereby i now store the real and imaginary components as separate elements in the double[] y and double[] yDot parameters (say real(i) = y[i*2] and imag(i) = y[i*2 + 1]). Then, on each iteration i then can use something like http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/complex/Complex.html to create complex instances and perform the actual complex arithmetic. The results of these ODE's then need to be stored back into yDot in a similar manner. When simulating this approach in matlab, the outputs are identical to using the complex numbers directly. Consequently, when porting to java, the results of the integration are also within tolerance (some tiny differences (+- 1e-8) due to implementation of integrator and FP issues possibly).